# Matching similar words using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

Hi all: I need to match similar words using RexEx. For example, if I have a pattern which contains a word like "autonomous", it should match the word "autonomy" without matching "autonomous". 
Example Code:

```
void modify(string word)
{
string input = "This island is a colony; however,it is autonomous and " + 
"receives no orders from the mother country, autonomy, N.";
string pattern = @",\s" + word + @"\s[v|n|adj]\.";//word = "autonomous";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
string output = reg.Replace(input, ".");
}
```

Comment: Sorry. My apologies to the ladies.

Comment: are you sure your code matches the autonomous.

Comment: @habib: That is what I don't want.

Comment: what do you want to do? more info

Comment: @FadelMS if you dont want to match autonomous use `(?!autonomous)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
string s= "This island is a colony; however,it is autonomous and receives no orders from the mother country, autonomy, N.";;
string pattern="autonomous";
Regex r=new Regex(@"\b(?!"+pattern+")"+pattern.Substring(0,pattern.Length/2)+@".*?\b");
r.Replace(s,".");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're going to be able to easily achieve with a Regex alone.

You should take a look at pattern matching algorithms. There's [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091257/how-to-recognize-similar-words-with-difference-in-spelling) that covers this topic.