# C# string comparision 'ö' 'oe' 'o'

Tags: c#, string-comparison, culture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to recognize similar words with difference in spelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091257/how-to-recognize-similar-words-with-difference-in-spelling)

I am trying to get returned true while comparing these 3 strings:
'voest', 'vost' and 'vöst' (German culture), because it is the same word.
(In fact, only oe and ö are the same, but e.g. for a DB collation CI it is the same which is correct, because 'vost' is a misstyped 'voest')

string.Compare(..) / string.Equals(..) returns always false no matter what arguments I provide to that method.

How to make string.Compare() / Equals(..) return true ?

Comment: And question is: how to make string.Compare return true or how i can build new method to return true for exaple showed above?

Comment: Linguistics are very complicated. Let class `String` take care of its job (work with string contents represented by bytes) and manage meanings of your words in your logic. This is just suggestion and my opinion of course.

Comment: I do not think it is possible with string.Compare to output true for 'voest' comparing to 'vost', ever.

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp

Although I dont think it's possible, because o, oe and ö aren't the same chars even if you think of different cultures.

Comment: @Mike and how would you achieve voest and vöst to be the same ?

Comment: I would check for 'ö' in your string, replace it with 'oe' and 'o', then check both strings with .Equals() method.

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me Create a custom class, to run whenever string.Compare returns false, to compare the strings again, but then with your logic. As I can imagine that 'oe' not always equals 'o', in different words e.g. This would be a lot of work I can imagine.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a custom comparer which ignores umlauts:

```
class IgnoreUmlautComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    Dictionary<char, char> umlautReplacer = new Dictionary<char, char>()
    {
        {'ä','a'}, {'Ä','A'},
        {'ö','o'}, {'Ö','O'},
        {'ü','u'}, {'Ü','U'},
    };
    Dictionary<string, string> pseudoUmlautReplacer = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"ae","a"}, {"Ae","A"},
        {"oe","o"}, {"Oe","O"},
        {"ue","u"}, {"Ue","U"},
    };

    private IEnumerable<char> ignoreUmlaut(string s)
    {
        char value;
        string replaced = new string(s.Select(c => umlautReplacer.TryGetValue(c, out value) ? value : c).ToArray());
        foreach (var kv in pseudoUmlautReplacer)
            replaced = replaced.Replace(kv.Key, kv.Value);
        return replaced;
    }

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        var xChars = ignoreUmlaut(x);
        var yChars = ignoreUmlaut(y);
        return xChars.SequenceEqual(yChars);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return ignoreUmlaut(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can use this comparer with `Enumerable` methods like [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx):

```
string[] allStrings = new[]{"voest","vost","vöst"};
bool allEqual = allStrings.Distinct(new IgnoreUmlautComparer()).Count() == 1;
// --> true
```

Comment: There is an error in your Equals method. The argument in the second line should be 'y', not 'x'

Comment: @Aaginor: thanks, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could try [IgnoreNonSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlstring.ignorenonspace.aspx) option in comparing. It won't solve voest - vost, but will help with vost-vöst.

```
int a = new CultureInfo("de-DE").CompareInfo.Compare("vost", "vöst", CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
// a = 0; strings are equal.
```

Comment: Did you actually test this and does it work for you? As I posted here it does not for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845211/culture-aware-string-comparison-for-umlaute/