# Culture-aware string comparison for Umlaute

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, string-comparison

I need to compare two strings in German language to check if they are equal and only differ in the use of umlaute. E.g. "Jörg" should be the same as "Joerg".

So I tried:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
int compareResult = ci.CompareInfo.Compare("jörg", "joerg", CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
```

as well as

```
int compareResult = String.Compare("jörg", "joerg", true, ci);
```

(or are those two equal anyway?)

However, this does not work and will return `1`. It is the same for all umlauts ö,ü and ä. If I compare `strasse`and `straße` in the same way, this does work and returns `0`?!

Thanks for any ideas! This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13562495/1537195) suggests that mine should work.

Comment: There are not many so why don't you just replace them (`"Jörg".Replace("ö","oe")`)?

Comment: There a lots of workarounds, sure, but I don't see why the direct way does not work.

Comment: [Coinkindez? Please see the discussion here!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845872/why-is-ss-equal-to-the-german-sharp-s-character-%C3%9F/29846396#29846396) TLTR? It doesn't work becasue it shouldn't! `Poet != Pöt` etc..

Comment: Not sure what you want to tell us. You are aware, that the discussion you linked was derived from the question here?! ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# string comparision 'ö' 'oe' 'o'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562304/c-sharp-string-comparision-%c3%b6-oe-o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and found no other solution then replacing them e.g. by a extension. As far as i know there is no "direct" solution for this.

```
public static string ReplaceUmlaute(this string s) 
{
    return s.Replace("ä", "ae").Replace("ö", "oe").Replace("ü", "ue").Replace("Ä", "AE").Replace("Ö", "OE").Replace("Ü", "UE");
}
```

Result:

```
int compareResult = String.Compare("jörg".ReplaceUmlaute(), "joerg", true, ci); // 0
```

Comment: Any idea why? Is this a bug in the framework or by design? If ß works, umlaute for sure should work as well?!

Comment: what about â á à ? They are different characters like ä.I would say ae is a workaround to display those characters where they are not supported.

Comment: @silent: why do you exptect it to return 0 if you compare `ö` and `oe`, that are completely  different strings. The fact that other cultures don't have the `ö` and use `oe` as workaround does not cause it to do the same in germany. So you need some kind of dictionary to map the umlaut with another representation that means the same for you.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ß and ss is completly the same case - and this does work. So why should ö and oe not work?

Comment: @silent: valid point and to be honest, i have no idea why `ß` and `ss` are treated the same both in german culture or any other(even `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`). I guess it has to do with the comment [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449.aspx): _" Linguistically (in Windows), "ss" is equal to 
the German essetz: 'ß' character in both en-US and de-DE cultures."_

Comment: Character expansion occurs in cases where one letter represents one character, but that one character sorts as if it were two. For example, ß (eszett) is equivalent to ss in both German/Germany and German/Switzerland locales. However, ß is equivalent to sz in the German/Austria locale. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242117%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: @fubo Thanks for the link. Still does not entirely convice me, though ;-) But that's not your fault but rather Microsoft's... In German ö is just as equal to oe as ß is to ss I would argue.

Comment: @silent i'm with you but Microsoft didn't implement that. Don't kill the bringer of bad news :-)

Comment: @fubo I didn't ;-) Upvoted already but want to keep it open a bit longer. Maybe someone has another killer idea...

Comment: @silent: fyi, i've asked a question about [why ”ss” is equal to the german sharp-s character 'ß'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845872/why-is-ss-equal-to-the-german-sharp-s-character-%C3%9F).

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, I saw that and the answer makes kinda sense

Answer (score 0):

Hope, .net6 upgrade will help to resolve the issue in invariant mode.

Ref: [Culture creation and case mapping in globalization-invariant mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/6.0/culture-creation-invariant-mode?source=recommendations)