# Foldcase conversion between (German) lower ß (U+00DF) and upper ẞ (U+1E9E)?

Tags: string, unicode, string-comparison, raku, unicode-string

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Development_of_a_capital_form), in 2017 using an uppercase `ẞ` (Unicode `U+1E9E`) was officially adopted--at least as an option--for what may in fact be a subset of fully-capitalized words in German:

*In June of that year, the Council for German Orthography officially adopted a rule that ⟨ẞ⟩ would be an option for capitalizing ⟨ß⟩ besides the previous capitalization as ⟨SS⟩ (i.e., variants STRASSE and STRAẞE would be accepted as equally valid).[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Substitution_and_all_caps)*

It seems like this addition to the German language would greatly simplify case-comparisons between strings (so-called "case-folding" or "fold-case" comparisons). Note, I started this inquiry trying to understand Raku's (a.k.a. Perl6's) implementation, but the question in fact seems to generalize to other programming languages. Here is Raku's default implementation--starting with 13 words from [rfdr_Regeln_2017.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20170706162042/http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2017.pdf#) that have been lowercased (via Raku's `.lc` function):

```perl
~$ cat TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ.txt
maß straße grieß spieß groß grüßen außen außer draußen strauß beißen fleiß heißen
~$ raku -ne '.words>>.match(/^ <:Ll>+ $/).say;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ.txt
(｢maß｣ ｢straße｣ ｢grieß｣ ｢spieß｣ ｢groß｣ ｢grüßen｣ ｢außen｣ ｢außer｣ ｢draußen｣ ｢strauß｣ ｢beißen｣ ｢fleiß｣ ｢heißen｣)
~$ raku -ne '.uc.say;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ.txt
MASS STRASSE GRIESS SPIESS GROSS GRÜSSEN AUSSEN AUSSER DRAUSSEN STRAUSS BEISSEN FLEISS HEISSEN
~$ raku -ne '.fc.say;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ.txt
mass strasse griess spiess gross grüssen aussen ausser draussen strauss beissen fleiss heissen
```

I'm suprised that Raku's `fc` fold-case implementation essentially converts to lowercase `ss`. It's no surprise then that trying to search for `eq` string equality between the upper/lower "round-tripped" words and the original are all `False`:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'for .words {print $_.uc.lc eq $_.lc }; "".put;'  TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ.txt
FalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalse
```

Fold-cased (`.fc`) words match, but they do so on the basis of `ss` characters, not `ß`:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'for .words {print $_.uc.lc eq $_.fc }; "".put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ.txt
TrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrue
```

---

Starting from a capital-ẞ, taking just one capitalized/uppercase word again demonstrates the dichotomy:

```perl
~$ echo "straße STRASSE STRAẞE" | raku -ne ' .put for .words;'
straße
STRASSE
STRAẞE
~$ echo "straße STRASSE STRAẞE" | raku -ne ' .lc.say for .words;'
straße
strasse
straße
~$ echo "straße STRASSE STRAẞE" | raku -ne ' for .words { say $_.lc eq "straße" };'
True
False
True
~$ echo "straße STRASSE STRAẞE" | raku -ne ' for .words { say $_.lc eq $_.fc };'
False
True
False
```

Have any programming languages instituted a `foldcase` conversion between  lowercase `ß` <--> uppercase `ẞ`, by default? What programming languages have added lowercase `ß` <--> uppercase `ẞ` conversion, as an option (or via a library)? Many Questions/Answers on StackOverflow pre-date the 2017 decision, so I'm looking for up-to-date answers.

[ADDENDUM: I note via this [FAQ](https://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#13) that the Unicode Consortium's rules appear to be at odds with the 2017 decision of the Council for German Orthography].

Comment: cf [a reddit comment I wrote about a year ago about that `ẞ` decision as it relates to PLs, their implementations, and MoarVM](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/comments/qddpib/comment/hjlofnj/).

Comment: "List programming languages that have feature X" is not a legitimate SO question.

Comment: @n.m. Reference? Also, what's preventing you from explaining the Raku implementation as detailed above?

Comment: @raiph Since you're a Raku expert maybe you could explain if Raku's implementation of case-folding differs from languages such as Java, C++, C#, and Perl? And maybe incorporating data from here: https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CaseFolding.txt and policy from here: https://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#13 (and subsequent) would be nice, too!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask There is no actual problem to be solved, for one. Not sure what exactly to explain. `straße` must casefold-compare equal to `STRASSE` which must casefold-compare equal to `strasse` (which is a legitimate spelling in Swiss German).

Comment: (contd) "Raku's fc fold-case implementation essentially converts to lowercase ss" This mapping is mandated by Unicode (the very same data file you link to in you comment above) and there are good reasons for that. Why would raku (or any other language indeed) do something non-standard? What kind of problem would it solve?

Comment: Defined in *Unicode technical standard* [UTS 10 Unicode Collation Algorithm](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Special_Cases).

Comment: @n.m.   Yes, I researched the answer after I wrote the question. Now I have to interpret the Unicode Consortium's rules. As of 2017 you have a German governmental body mandating something that the Unicode Consortium disallows. So there IS a question here--"how to handle this progammatically?"--but if no one else answer I guess I'll have to answer the question myself.

Comment: you have a German governmental body mandating something that the Unicode Consortium disallows" This is simply not true. There is no contradiction anywhere. The German Orthography Council rules on *orthography*, while Unicode concerns itself with *string matching*. The two are fully orthogonal. The German Orthography Council tells you which spellings are correct German. The Unicode consortium tells you which strings are considered equal when case is ignored. Strings do not have to be correctly spelled words to be compared.

Comment: *So there IS a question here--"how to handle this progammatically?* So why not ask *that* question instead? The answer would depend on what you mean by "it". If you want a program that can casefold-compare strings, then follow Unicode. If you want a program that correctly flips German words between all-caps and normal case convention according to German spelling rules, then you better start training your large language model now, because you can't do that without understanding what German words mean in context.

Comment: From the linked FAQ: "Since the [Unicode] case folding rules do not vary by language or context, this makes them unsuitable as the basis for displaying or transforming text for human consumption." Unicode case folding is not intended to match all language casing rules. And in fact it is provably *impossible* for it to do so.  In some languages, capital "I" is not the uppercase version of lowercase "i".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### 1. Lowercase/Uppercase:

***In Raku, the default conversion from lowercase German `ß` is to uppercase `SS`, but this can be overcome (as shown below).***

The Unicode Consortium has a special [FAQ](https://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#11) on these letters in the German language. However, if one wants to work around the first `uc` uppercasing issue using  Raku, the `"ß" => "ẞ"` characters can be appropriately `trans`lated ***prior to*** calling the bog-standard `uc` uppercase  method/function:

```perl
~$ cat TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
Maß Straße Grieß Spieß Groß Grüßen Außen Außer Draußen Strauß Beißen Fleiß Heißen
raku -ne '.uc.put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
MASS STRASSE GRIESS SPIESS GROSS GRÜSSEN AUSSEN AUSSER DRAUSSEN STRAUSS BEISSEN FLEISS HEISSEN
~$ raku -ne '.trans("ß" => "ẞ").put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
Maẞ Straẞe Grieẞ Spieẞ Groẞ Grüẞen Auẞen Auẞer Drauẞen Strauẞ Beiẞen Fleiẞ Heiẞen
~$ raku -ne '.trans("ß" => "ẞ").uc.put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
MAẞ STRAẞE GRIEẞ SPIEẞ GROẞ GRÜẞEN AUẞEN AUẞER DRAUẞEN STRAUẞ BEIẞEN FLEIẞ HEIẞEN
```

The code above works to uppercase text with `ẞ` instead of `SS`--and in true Raku/Perl spirit--there's more than one way to do it (TMTOWTDI):

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.trans("ß" => "ẞ").uc.put;' file
~$ raku -e '.trans("ß" => "ẞ").uc.put for lines();' file
~$ raku -e 'put .trans("ß" => "ẞ").uc for lines();' file
~$ raku -e 'slurp.trans("ß" => "ẞ").uc.put;' file
~$ raku -e 'slurp.trans( "\x[00DF]" => "\x[1E9E]" ).uc.put;' file
~$ raku -e 'slurp.trans("LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S".uniparse => "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S".uniparse).uc.put;' file
```

---

##### 2. Foldcase:

***The Unicode Consortium promulgates a rule that foldcase pairs should be stable (according to the [Unicode Casefolding Stability Policy](https://www.unicode.org/policies/stability_policy.html#Case_Folding)).***

As for `fc` foldcase stability, I had hoped that prior conversion of `"ß" => "ẞ"` would provide a "30th-uppercase character" that would act as a bicameral foldcase partner of lowercase `ß` (in a pair). The code below seems promising in that starting with a small sample of mixed-case text, you can "round-trip" from uppercase-to-lowercase, and  still have output text matching lowercase:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'for .words {print $_.uc.lc eq $_.lc }; "".put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
FalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalse
~$ raku -ne 'for .words {print $_.trans("ß" => "ẞ").uc.lc eq $_.lc }; "".put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
TrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrue
```

However, the `fc` foldcase code below shows that the present course of action is to take an uppercase `ẞ` and convert to lowercase `ss` (not to lowercase `ß`). Essentially `.fc` foldcase converts uppercase `ẞ` or `SS` to lowercase `ss`, regardless:

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.trans("ß" => "ẞ").fc.put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
mass strasse griess spiess gross grüssen aussen ausser draussen strauss beissen fleiss heissen
~$ raku -ne 'for .words {print $_.trans("ß" => "ẞ").uc.fc eq $_.fc }; "".put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
TrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrueTrue
~$ raku -ne 'for .words {print $_.trans("ß" => "ẞ").uc.lc eq $_.fc }; "".put;' TO_ẞ_OR_NOT_TO_ẞ_tclc.txt
FalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalse
```

Changes anticipated? According to a 2017 StackOverflow post, "[Just wait half a century.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45103163/7270649)"

https://raku.org