# Linq best match option

Tags: c#, linq

i would like to know how i can find the best match word in the database using Linq

for example ->

user ask for "playtation" and linq returns "playstation, playstation 4, playstation 3"

Comment: Could you show us what code you are using, or even what you have tried?

Comment: check out full-text search in SQL Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: Duplicate of [how to recognize similar words with difference in spelling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091257/how-to-recognize-similar-words-with-difference-in-spelling)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299996/find-sql-records-containing-similar-strings

Answer (score -1):

```
var query = from item in source
            where item.StartWith("playstation")
            return item;

foreach(var q in query)
      Console.WriteLine(q);
```